# Visa4Uk or AccessUk

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

Noticed that there is a [new service](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa) (see bottom of page under Apply) to apply for a visitor visa to the UK.

In the past I have used the Visa4Uk service to apply for my visa (twice), and am very comfortable with this service. 
I'm applying again for a visitor visa and now notice that there is a new service "Access UK" which is now available to apply.

My question is can I use the old Visa4Uk service or do I now have to use the new Access UK service.

Answer (score 6):

The [UK.Gov](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa) website is very clear on which site you should use.

From that site :

> What service you use depends on the visa you’re applying for.
>
> You can apply using the Access UK service for
>
> - Standard Visitor visa
> - Marriage Visitor visa
> - Permitted Paid Engagement visa
>
> Apply using the Visa4UK service for all other visas,
> including study and work visas.